# Has error when play mp3 from local by http in android emulator

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm studing xamarin and stuck with the problem. I have android emulator on the windows machine and i debug xamarin application on it. It uses MediaPlayer to play mp3 from local iis server and throw exception on method player.Prepare().

```
player.SetDataSource("http://10.0.2.2/AaronNeville-CrazyLove.mp3");
player.Prepare();
```

Where is cut from log:

> 01-11 21:34:19.914: E/NuCachedSource2(1776): source returned error -1, 0 retries left
>
> 01-11 21:34:19.962: E/GenericSource(1776): initFromDataSource, cannot create extractor!
>
> 01-11 21:34:19.962: E/GenericSource(1776): Failed to init from data source!
>
> 01-11 21:34:19.963: D/NuPlayerDriver(1776): notifyListener_l(0xe6799800), (100, 1, -2147483648, -1), loop setting(0, 0)
>
> 01-11 21:34:19.964: E/MediaPlayerNative(9653): error (1, -2147483648)

1. When i play mp3 from https internet server it works good, but by http get a same error.
2. I don't see any traffic from an android device in iis log and a network monitor and removed any firewall constraints on the windows.
3. I can play "http://10.0.2.2/AaronNeville-CrazyLove.mp3" from a device chrome successful.

Please, give me some fresh ideas what to do.

Comment: Newer API levels require HTTPS, otherwise you have add an clear text exception to your app: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55997456/4984832

Comment: @SushiHangover I tried it and it works :) Thank you very much, you saved my mental health today.